# ASP.net and Using Frameworks / Libraries / Methodologies

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, blueprint-css

I have built several personal sites and now I and going to rebuild an existing one.  I want to standardize on jQuery and Blueprint CSS.

I used to use a Master page for everything but that does not seem to match real well with something like Blueprint. Not to mention the pain of the master page renaming of the controls ids and applying them in js.

Kinda just looking for suggestions on how to use newer libraries / frameworks / methodologies on the new asp.net site.

Should I ditch Master pages altogether?

Should I stop creating my pages with VS page creator GUI and move to building most or all the html and server objects in code dynamically?

Should I look at ASP.net MVC as well?

Any other suggestions appreciated.

Thanks,
Erik

Answer (score 1):

If you stay with MasterPages, you can reference your Server Controls from your Client Side jQuery like:

$('#<%= MyControl.UniqueID %>').

Answer (score 1):

I would look at ASP.NET MVC if you are going to try and use those frameworks.  It allows much greater control over the HTML.

ASP.NET controls don't always render the simplest of markup, which can complicate the process of using additional frameworks.